# Hyerlink Images in Outlook 2003 Signature

Tags: hyperlink, microsoft-outlook-2003, email-signature

How do you add multiple hyper-linked images in the signature using Outlook 2003? It works when adding one image, however not with 2 or 3 different hyper-linked images.. Any suggestions?